# Google Finance API -

Tags: google-api, yahoo-api

In google finance, I cannot get the stock low, stock high and few other information. Is there a way to get the same?

For example: http://finance.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:AIAENG

Above link is giving very limited information like stock name, last traded price & time, change, change percentage How can i get stock low and high for the day using google finance.

Note : I tried using Yahoo Finance API but it is not working for Indian stock whereas it is working fine for NASDAQ and other exchange. So please suggest if I can use any other site API to get the necessary info of a stock

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience, plus both Google and Yahoo APIs can't be used for commercial purposes (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-finance-apis/dcKPEcDxDpU/IxBtLL7s8psJ). But I've found Alpha Vantage a great alternative, just need to follow their documentation (which is very simple) to get a JSON.

An example of getting a JSON output in PHP:

> $url = file_get_contents('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&outputsize=full&symbol=AAPL&apikey='.$apiKey);
>   
> $decoded = json_decode($url, true);